# How can I split query result to create new table in MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to split the query result in MSSQL.

Example is below:

```
ID (PK)      BorrowID
1            1,3,4
2            4,5
3            2,3
4            1,6
5            2,7
```

I want to create new tables using upper table data.

```
NewID(PK)    ID      BorrowID
1            1       1
2            1       3
3            1       4
4            2       4
5            2       5
```

So I want to split the BorrowID Data to create new tables.

How can i get this?

I already try to use SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX function, but it doesn't well.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of commas and (ii) are you going to export the data only once?

Comment: There are no limits. I want to export the data only once.

Comment: What is the length of largest string you have?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to get individual values for your comma seperated list in MSSQL,

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ID,BorrowID) as NewID,ID,BorrowID 
FROM ( SELECT A.*,
         Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [BorrowID] 
     FROM  
     (
         SELECT ID, 
             CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE( [BorrowID], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
          FROM [Table]
     ) AS A CROSS APPLY  [Data].nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))d;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Sql Server 2016+ you may use String_split:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by t1.id, t2.borrowid) as newid, t1.id, t2.borrowid
 from t1 
  cross apply (select value as borrowid from string_split(t1.borrowid, ',')) as t2
```

Returns:

```
newid   id  borrowid
1   1   1
2   1   3
3   1   4
4   2   4
5   2   5
6   3   2
7   3   3
```